# Injecting CSS using Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to remove an element by injecting JS into [webpage](https://thecrypto.app):

```
javascript:(function() {
  var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.innerHTML = '.ls-wrapper.ls-in-out { display: none; }';
  parent.appendChild(style);
})()
```

The div holding the link to Google Play should disappear, but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? I am trying this on Chrome Console. Here are class names `.ls-wrapper` and `.ls-in-out`:

[image]

Comment: Is your CSS specificity high enough?

Comment: You could target just the Google Play button by using `document.querySelectorAll(".ls-wrapper.ls-in-out").item(2).style.display = "none";`

Comment: The screenshot you've provided doesn't show the most important part, which would be: Are you seeing the `<style>` in your `<head>`? If you scroll down in the Styles explorer, do you see your style being applied?

Comment: You've got an inline style specifying `display: block` that will override any stylesheet reference unless you put `!important` after the property value. See [what is the priority of styling an element in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41226030)

Comment: @HereticMonkey, `!important` did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the priority of styling an element in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41226030/what-is-the-priority-of-styling-an-element-in-html)

Answer (score -1):

Try

style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(youCssHere));
instead of modifying innerHTML