# How can I override external CSS?

Tags: css, overriding, external

On my Shopify website, I have a plug-in that's embedded. The style sheet for that plug-in is external. How can I override it?

I'm trying to remove where it says "powR" (blue logo). See picture

I've tried using "!important" but it doesn't work.

**UPDATE: Picture Added**
[see problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifgvK.png)

Comment: possible duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369919/does-embedded-css-always-override-external-css

Comment: you need add valid image url

Comment: I added the picture, please check it out. I'm trying to get rid of that logo (circled). Hope this makes my question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

To override any CSS, you need a new style that is more specific.

CSS styles are applied in the order that they are written. If you have two identical selectors, the one that is read last will override any duplicate properties in the previous style. But, if one use more specific (i.e. more restrictive) than the other, then those properties will take precedence.

In your case, if you simply find the selector that is being used for the style you want to override, you can copy it into a CSS file that is loaded after the plug-in's CSS file, and then override whatever you want.

For more information about specificity, [see this article on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I added the picture, please check it out. I'm trying to get rid of that logo (circled). Hope this makes my question more clear.

Comment: Well, it says "Upgrade to remove this logo!", so I would recommend you simply upgrade you account because hiding/removing the logo without upgrading may be against their user agreement. You should support the developers who built your platform. That said, the easiest way to remove it would be something like `.powrMark { display: none !important; }`.