# font size not changing in media query in css

Tags: html, css

I have this html code:

```
<div class="guide">
  <h2><b style="font-size: 3vw">filler</b></h2>
  <h1><b style="font-size: 3.2vw"> Who's cuter? Click to Choose.</b></h1>
</div>
```

and this is my css media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .guide {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

The color changes to blue but the font size doesn't. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to use `font-size: 25px !important` since you have inline style.

Comment: Inline styles (Styles defined on an element) take precedence over external css (css defined in another script).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `style` overrides css

Comment: Inline css is overriding your css. It has more specificity than css selector.

Comment: Or instead of digging a deeper whole with `!important`s, you can move the inline styles to CSS.

Comment: Did you write <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> code in your head?

Answer (score 0):

You have inline styles on children of the `.guide` div. Try adding rules to those elements in your media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .guide,
  .guide h1 b,
  .guide h2 b {
    font-size: 25px !important;
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS in media-query is overwritten by your inline-CSS applied in your html.

You can use `!important` in your external CSS.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .guide {
    font-size: 25px !important;
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

However, the `!important` rule is most times considered a bad practice. A better solution could be to use no inline-CSS at all and include it all in your external CSS.

Check here: [Does embedded css always override external css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369919/does-embedded-css-always-override-external-css)

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you have added `inline css` in HTML code, which has the highest priority.

Remove inline CSS from your html code. and it will work.

```
<h1><b> Who's cuter? Click to Choose.</b></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code.

```css
.title {
  font-size: 3vw;
}
.text {
  font-size: 3.2vw;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .title, 
  .text {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>
    <b class="title">filler</b>
  </h2>
  <h1>
    <b class="text">Who's cuter? Click to Choose.</b>
  </h1>
</div>
```

It will work.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Remove inline styles and use class selectors for the same and that way your css rules will take effect.

Answer (score 0):

your code not work beacuse you use inline-Css

try this code : 
html :

```
 <div>
  <h2>
    <b class="title">filler</b>
  </h2>
  <h1>
    <b class="text">Who's cuter? Click to Choose.</b>
  </h1>
</div>
```

and Css :

```
 .title {
        font-size: 3vw;
      }
      .text {
        font-size: 3.2vw;
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
        .title, 
        .text {
          font-size: 25px;
          color: blue;
        }
      }
```